# Solve empty file issue in Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I try download a file in Google Colab

```
  train_url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBjLm79vkDqn8GulvvKb6FLH5ghmBpMq/view?usp=sharing"
  !wget -O train.csv -b train_url &
  train = pd.read_csv(r"./train.csv",dtype = np.float32)
```

Two Questions:

1. After download this file, however the file always shows as 0 byte, which means it's a empty file. Not sure why
2. I want waiting the file is downloaded, then the pd can start to read the csv file.
   [Related Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1011228/bash-script-not-waiting-for-wget-to-finish-download)

Answer (score 1):

you can read the file directly using pandas

```
train_url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBjLm79vkDqn8GulvvKb6FLH5ghmBpMq/view?usp=sharing"
load_url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={train_url.split('/')[-2]}'
train = pd.read_csv(load_url,dtype = np.float32)
>>>print(train.head())
   label  pixel0  pixel1  pixel2  ...  pixel780  pixel781  pixel782  pixel783
0      1       0       0       0  ...         0         0         0         0
1      0       0       0       0  ...         0         0         0         0
2      1       0       0       0  ...         0         0         0         0
3      4       0       0       0  ...         0         0         0         0
4      0       0       0       0  ...         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: The f has some problem but overrall looks good. ```load_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+train_url.split('/')[-2]```

Comment: f string was introduced in [python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)